# Ignore clean command in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a project to compile with a lot of makefiles including a clean command. That's why i always have to start over again if there is an error (because the clean command is called in many Makefiles)

Question:

Is there any possibility to tell make to ignore the clean command? I would have to touch > 100 Makefiles otherwise. I would like make to start on the last error, not compiling all done stuff again

Example Makefile entries:

```
clean: cleansubdirs $(DIR) $(DIR1)
   $(DIR2)
```

Comment: It seems weird to me. `make` doesn't call clean normally. It needs to be called manually. Are you sure cleanup is called on fail?

Comment: Cleanup is called if i start make again because it is set in the makefiles

Comment: Then, I am afraid, you cannot fix it easly.

Comment: Depending on how your makefile is written, you could use `make RM=:` but this requires a make variable like `RM = rm` in the makefile (and used consistently in all the clean targets).

Comment: This is plainly wrong to start every build with "make clean" and it must be fixed ASAP. Writing 100+ files like that is beyond good and evil. Use shell/sed to batch edit and read carefully a couple of books about make starting from the very beginning. That's the only good advice you can get.

Comment: @Matt thank you for you answer. The project is build from source in a fixed Interval. It was not made for incremental builds, that's why where are "clean:" commands in so much Makefiles. Do you know how i have to edit the command. I know there are several lines for each command, maybe it will be enough to comment out just the "clean:" part?

Comment: If you show us a typical makefile, maybe we can tell you how to modify it.

Comment: Added an example

Comment: Show us how the `clean` target is being reached instead of what it does.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to redefine the recipe of an explicit target as simple as that:

> noclean.mk

```
clean:;
cleansubdirs:;
# more stuff...
```

Now run `make -f Makefile -f noclean.mk` and it will work without actual cleaning files. However, make will issue several warnings about "overriding/ignoring old recipes".